# Error: invalid signer or provider (argument="signerOrProvider", value={}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)

Tags: blockchain, ethers.js, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

```
import { AlphaRouter } from "@uniswap/smart-order-router";
import { ethers, BigNumber } from "ethers"; // Import BigNumber from ethers

import { Token, CurrencyAmount, TradeType, Percent } from "@uniswap/sdk-core";

// GET DATA RIGHT

const V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = "0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45 ";

// GET PRICE

const chainId = 1;

const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(
  "https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/nXfnz5sSmJgr640j4mCrUZaOtldbLzvb"
);

const router = new AlphaRouter({
  chainId: chainId,
  provider: provider,
});

const name0 = "Wrapped Ether";
const symbol0 = "WETH";
const decimal0 = 18;
const address0 = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2";

const name1 = "DAI";
const symbol1 = "DAI";
const decimal1 = 18;
const address1 = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F";

const WETH = new Token(chainId, address0, decimal0, symbol0, name0);
const DAI = new Token(chainId, address1, decimal1, symbol1, name1);

export const swapUpdatePrice = async (
  inputAmount,
  slippageAmount,
  deadline,
  walletAddress
) => {
  const percentSlippage = new Percent(slippageAmount, 100);
  const wei = ethers.parseUnits(inputAmount.toString(), decimal0);
  console.log(inputAmount);
  console.log(wei);
  const weiNumber = parseFloat(ethers.formatUnits(wei, decimal0));

  // Convert BigNumber to BigInt
  const currencyAmount = CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(WETH, weiNumber);
  console.log(currencyAmount);

  console.log(provider);

  const route = await router.route(currencyAmount, DAI, TradeType.EXACT_INPUT, {
    recipient: walletAddress,
    slippageTolerance: percentSlippage,
    deadline: deadline,
  });

  const transaction = {
    data: route.methodParameters.calldata,
    to: V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS,
    value: BigNumber.from(route.methodParameters.value),
    from: walletAddress,
    gasPrice: BigNumber.from(route.gasPriceWei),
    gasLimit: ethers.hexlify(1000000),
  };

  const quoteAmountOut = route.quote.toFixed(6);
  const ratio = (inputAmount / quoteAmountOut).toFixed(3);

  console.log(quoteAmountOut, ratio);

  return [transaction, quoteAmountOut, ratio];
};
```

[image]

Although the provider is defined and also it's valid , It's throwing an error " Invalid Signer Or Provider "

Answer (score 2):

your ethers.js version is v5.7.0.

get provider in v6:

`const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/nXfnz5sSmJgr640j4mCrUZaOtldbLzvb");`

get provider in v5:

`const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/nXfnz5sSmJgr640j4mCrUZaOtldbLzvb");`

Comment: I'm using ethers version 6.6.7  ( "ethers": "^6.7.0" )

Answer (score 1):

just dug this up while getting this error myself - you need to install ethers 5 for this (I used 5.7.2), and you also need a signer for it

```
const _Provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("YOUR_ENDPOINT_HERE")
const _signer = new Wallet(PRIVATE KEY HERE (non-hex),_Provider);
const _chainId = INSERT CHAIN ID HERE;
```

`const router = new AlphaRouter({chainId:_chainId,provider:_signer.provider});`